# Angular2 rxjs/Subject import - can't load vendor/rxjs/index.js

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I haven't changed anything inside angular cli structure. I tried to import Subject from rxjs and create Subject object like this:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {

  nameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  ...
```

and there is an error while loading my webpage

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/index.js 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM35531:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/index.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/index.js as "rxjs" from http://localhost:4200/app/global.service.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/index.js(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/rxjs/index.js(…)
```

index.html system.js load

```
  <script>
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
      System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

system.config.ts (js compiled successfully)

```
// SystemJS configuration file, see links for more information
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs
// https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

/***********************************************************************************************
 * User Configuration.
 **********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'firebase': 'vendor/firebase/firebase.js',
  'angularfire2': 'vendor/angularfire2'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  angularfire2: {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'angularfire2.js'
  }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

  // App specific barrels.
  'app',
  'app/shared',
  'app/homepage',
  'app/loginpage',
  'app/registerpage',
  /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
  cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js'
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

and default angular-cli-build.js

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'angularfire2/**/*.js',
      'firebase/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

Inside vendor/rxjs I have all files that are under node_modules/rxjs. There is no file like index.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should import Subject from

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';  //full bundle
```

Or

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';//deep import , minimal import as required.
```

Answer (score 2):

The most correct is:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
```